# A particle of mass $m$ moves under a retarding force that is proportional to the cube of the speed

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

> A particle of mass $m$ moves under a retarding force that is proportional to the cube of the speed. Find how long it takes to travel a distance $d$ from the instant speed was $u$.

---

I've been stuck on this question for an hour now.  Can someone please point me in the right direction? The answer is

$$ \dfrac{d}{u} + \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{k}{m}d^2 $$

My initial equation is:

$ a = - \dfrac{kv^3}{m} $ then trying $\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ or $\dfrac{dv}{dx}v$ for $a$, without to much success.

Here is my thought process:

$$ v \dfrac{dv}{dx} = - \dfrac{kv^3}{m} $$
$$  \dfrac{dv}{dx} = - \dfrac{kv^2}{m}  $$
$$  \dfrac{dx}{dv} = - \dfrac{m}{kv^2}  $$
$$  x = - \dfrac{m}{k} \int v^{-2} dv $$
$$  x = \dfrac{m}{kv} + c $$

When $x = 0$ , $v = u$, therefor $c =  - \dfrac{m}{ku} $

So I have

$$  x = \dfrac{m}{kv} - \dfrac{m}{ku} $$

I've solved it......

$$  x + \dfrac{m}{ku} = \dfrac{m}{kv} $$
$$  \dfrac{m}{kv} = \dfrac{kux + m}{ku} $$

Cancel the $k$ on the numerator.

$$  \dfrac{m}{v} = \dfrac{kux + m}{u} $$

Take reciprocal of both sides.

$$  \dfrac{v}{m} = \dfrac{u}{kux + m} $$

$$  v= \dfrac{mu}{kux + m} $$
$$ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{mu}{kux + m} $$

Take reciprocal of both sides.

$$ \dfrac{dt}{dx} = \dfrac{kux + m}{mu} $$
$$ \dfrac{dt}{dx} = \dfrac{m + kux}{mu} $$
$$ \dfrac{dt}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{u} +  \dfrac{kx}{m}$$

$$ t = \int \Bigg[\dfrac{1}{u} +  \dfrac{kx}{m} \Bigg] dx $$

Using initial conditions $x = 0$ to $x = d$.

$$ t = \int_{x=0}^{x=d} \Bigg[\dfrac{1}{u} +  \dfrac{kx}{m} \Bigg] dx $$
$$ t = \Bigg[\dfrac{x}{u} +  \dfrac{kx^2}{2m} \Bigg]_{x=0}^{x=d}  dx $$

$$ t= \dfrac{d}{u} + \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{k}{m}d^2 $$

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail regarding your attempt solving the differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{kv^3}{m}$ for $v$? It's a separable equation so it should be fairly straight-forward

Comment: Given that our question involves time, I would recommend putting $\frac{dv}{dt}$ on the left instead of $v\frac{dv}{dx}.$ Then, once you have an explicit solution for $v$ in terms of $t$ you can integrate again to get $x$ in terms of $t.$

Comment: (also, just as a heads-up, it looks like the given solution actually uses $\frac{dv}{dt} = kv^3$ and just lets $k < 0.$)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is probably the more elegant one, but here is an alternative with tedious algebraic manipulations omitted for brevity.

From
$$
a = {\mathrm{d}v \over \mathrm{d}t} = -{kv^3 \over m}
$$
solve for $v(t)$
$$
\int{\mathrm{d}v \over v^3} = -\int{k \over m}\mathrm{d}t\\
{1 \over v^2} = {2kt \over m} + c.
$$
Applying the initial condition $v(0) = u$, we find $$c = {1 \over u^2}$$ and so $$v(t) = \sqrt{mu^2 \over 2ku^2t + m}.$$

Integrating $v(t)$ from $0$ to the unknown time $t_d$ should result in the desired distance $d$, so
$$
d = \int_0^{t_d}\sqrt{mu^2 \over 2ku^2t + m}\mathrm{d}t = {\sqrt{m} \over 2ku}\int_m^{2ku^2t_d + m}s^{-1/2}\mathrm{d}s = {\sqrt{2ku^2mt_d + m^2} - m\over ku}
$$
using the substitution $s = 2ku^2t+m$.
Solving for $t_d$ yields
$$
t_d = {k \over 2m}d^2 + {d \over u}.
$$